# Is there a way to provide custom property formatting with Serilog?

Tags: c#, logging, tostring, serilog, destructuring

I have a class `BackgroundTask` that I have set up to log events when things happen, such as when the task completes. For example, for the `Success` case, I call `Log.Verbose("{Task} completed successfully", this);` My default `ToString()` includes the progress, but for a completed task we know it's 100% so I would like to ignore it. I know that with numeric types you can pass in a custom format specifier string (like `"{IntProperty:p5}"`, which would render my int as a percentage with 5 decimal places), and I would like to be able to do the same, such as `Log.Information("{Task:Name}", this)`, which would pass in `"Name"` into my `ToString()` method.

I've tried adding lots of different methods like adding `ToString()`'s, (taking in nothing, a string, a string and `IFormatProvider`), implementing `IFormattable`, forcing stringification etc and nothing seems to work. I can see that Serilog is correctly parsing my format string: (`PropertyBinder.cs`, `ConstructNamedProperties()` line 111)
[image: Debug view of serilog code]

This calls `ConstructProperty()` which just ignores the `Format` property of the token, which explains why it's being ignored, but I was wondering if there was a way that would work that I haven't thought of.

*PS*
Yes I'm aware I have several options I *could* do, but I'd rather not do these:

1. Use a custom destructurer or manually pulling out the properties myself into an anonymous type - This essentially destroys the original object, which is exactly what I don't want (I still want the original value stored as a property). E.g. `Log.Information("{Task}", new {Name = this.Name, Id = this.Id});`
2. Manually call `ToString()` with my own format string - Same as (1), this destroys the original, and means it won't be stored with all it's information. E.g. `Log.Information("{Task}", this.ToString("Custom Format"));`
3. Create a property on my object like `ToStringFormat` before passing it into Serilog - This seems bad practice and just adds extra clutter, not to mention the concurrency issues. E.g. `this.Format = "Custom FOrmat"; Log.Information("{Task}", this);`

Comment: How are you logging the event to Serilog back out in your code? Overriding `ToString` on your logged type would normally be enough for this - perhaps you're also including `@` in the message template, which would skip calling `ToString`?

Comment: Yes overriding `ToString()` would let me change the ***default*** string representation, but I don't want the *default* representation. I want to be able to change it through the message template, not by modifying my `ToString()`. Here's an example:


```csharp
void Main()
{
 Point p = new();
 Log.Error("{Point}", p);   //Default ToString
 Log.Error("{Point:X}", p) ;//ToString("X")
 Log.Error("{Point:Y}", p) ;//ToString("Y")
}
```

Comment: Ah :+1: I think this is due to one of the rough edges in how Serilog (currently?) works... Will write up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the split between *capturing* and *formatting* in the Serilog pipeline.

In order for format strings like `:X` to be processed when rendering to a sink, the original object implementing `IFormattable` needs to be available.

But, because sinks often process events asynchronously, Serilog can't be sure that any given logged object is thread-safe, and so any unknown types are captured at the time/site of logging using `ToString()`.

To get around this, you need to tell Serilog that your `Point` class is an (essentially immutable) value type with:

```
    .Destructure.AsScalar(typeof(Point))
```

when the logger is configured. You can then implement `IFormattable` on `Point` and use `{Point:X}` etc. in templates.

Comment: That's done it for me, thanks very much :)

Comment: You're welcome 

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt Happy to ask as a separate question if you think it's appropriate, but how can I apply this for built-in types? In my case, we're logging `decimal` values to ElasticSearch, and when on rare occasion the first instance of a value that is submitted has no fractional component, ES types the index as `long`, and subsequent writes with values that do have fractional components fail until the index is rebuilt again.